# Boot resolution change in initramfs on laptop monitor and HDMI monitor

Tags: boot, luks, initramfs, hdmi, bootsplash

I have Linux Mint 17 on my laptop. Also I have 22'' monitor connected to laptop using HDMI cable. My disk if fully encrypted with LUKS and LVM. On boot I get graphical prompt to enter password for encrypted partitions. Screen resolution on on both laptop and external monitor is wrong when asking for password. Graphical prompt and linux mint logo is moved to top left corner on both monitors and rest of space is black. Resolution is correct only after I log in to my profile. This is what `xrandr` shows when I'm logged in:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3286 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+1920+312 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.1*+   40.1
   1360x768       59.8     60.0
   1024x768       60.0
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   640x480        59.9
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 298mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+
   1680x1050      59.9
   1600x900       60.0
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0
   1280x800       59.9
   1152x864       75.0
   1280x720       60.0
   1024x768       75.1     60.0
   832x624        74.6
   800x600        75.0     60.3
   640x480        75.0     60.0
   720x400        70.1
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

After mounting encrypted disk I can change resolution on monitors using `xrandr` command. But this command is unavailable with `initramfs`.

I was recently fixing another laptop screen brightness on boot using `initramfs` script and it worked. This script was setting brightness by echoing correct value to to `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness`. Can I also use something similar to change screen resolution somehow?

**UPDATE**

I've tried @mikeserv solution:

1. EDID files from monitors (not sure if they are correct):

   ```
   # cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-LVDS-1/edid > /lib/firmware/edid/1366x768.bin
   # cat /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1/edid > /lib/firmware/edid/1920x1080.bin

   # hexdump /lib/firmware/edid/1366x768.bin
   0000000 ff00 ffff ffff 00ff e430 033b 0000 0000
   0000010 1600 0401 2290 7813 610a 9ed5 5b5e 269a
   0000020 501a 0054 0000 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101
   0000030 0101 0101 0101 1de2 b456 0050 3038 3024
   0000040 0035 c258 0010 1900 13ec c656 0050 302e
   0000050 3024 0035 c258 0010 1900 0000 fe00 3500
   0000060 4833 3935 3180 3635 4857 0a34 0000 0000
   0000070 0000 3141 0096 0000 0100 0a01 2020 ac00
   0000080

   # hexdump /lib/firmware/edid/1920x1080.bin 
   0000000 ff00 ffff ffff 00ff d109 78a5 5445 0000
   0000010 1626 0301 3580 781e b72e a4d5 5456 279f
   0000020 500c a554 806b 0081 c081 8081 c0a9 00b3
   0000030 c0d1 0101 0101 3a02 1880 3871 402d 2c58
   0000040 0045 2a13 0021 1e00 0000 ff00 4c00 4339
   0000050 3030 3537 3039 3931 200a 0000 fd00 3200
   0000060 1e4c 1153 0a00 2020 2020 2020 0000 fc00
   0000070 4200 6e65 2051 4c47 3432 3035 200a d900
   0000080
   ```
2. Hook script for initramfs, loads `i915` module and include `EDID` files into `/lib/firmware/edid/` directory inside `initramfs` (I've checked and `EDID` files are inside initramfs)

   ```
   # cat /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/include-edid-data 
   #!/bin/sh

   PREREQ="udev"
   prereqs()
   {
      echo "$PREREQ"
   }

   case $1 in
   prereqs)
      prereqs
      exit 0
      ;;
   esac

   . /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions
   # Begin real processing below this line

   if [ ! -e "${DESTDIR}/lib/firmware/edid" ]; then
       mkdir -p "${DESTDIR}/lib/firmware/edid"
   fi

   if [ -r "/lib/firmware/edid/1366x768.bin" ]; then
      cp "/lib/firmware/edid/1366x768.bin" "${DESTDIR}/lib/firmware/edid/"
   fi

   if [ -r "/lib/firmware/edid/1920x1080.bin" ]; then
      cp "/lib/firmware/edid/1920x1080.bin" "${DESTDIR}/lib/firmware/edid/"
   fi

   manual_add_modules i915

   exit 0

   # chmod a+rx /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/include-edid-data
   # update-initramfs -u
   ```
3. On reboot I've added boot parameter (not sure if it should be HDMI-1 or HDMI1 or something else)

   ```
   drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=HDMI1:/lib/firmware/edid/1920x1080.bin
   ```
4. It didn't change anything. So I also tried:

   ```
   drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=HDMI-1:/lib/firmware/edid/1920x1080.bin
   drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=HDMI1:edid/1920x1080.bin
   drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=HDMI-1:edid/1920x1080.bin
   ```

No luck at all. Everything is like it was before I took steps from above.

I also want to add that when HDMI monitor id disconnected resolution on laptop monitor is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2**

Still not working. Steps I took:

1. Found out correct names for my monitors:

   ```
   $ for p in /sys/class/drm/*/status; do if [ "$(cat "$p")" == "connected" ]; then echo -n "$p" | awk -F '/' '{print $5}'; fi; done
   card0-HDMI-A-1
   card0-LVDS-1
   ```
2. Install `linux-doc` (to get docs describing creation of custom `EDID`), `dos2unix`, `make` (for compiling `EDID` files) packages

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install linux-doc dos2unix make
   ```
3. Create temporary directory for compilation and copy source files for `EDID`

   ```
   $ mkdir ~/Tmp/edid
   $ cd ~/Tmp/edid
   $ cp /usr/share/doc/linux-doc/EDID/* .
   $ rm *.S
   $ cp /usr/share/doc/linux-doc/EDID/1920x1080.S .
   $ cp /usr/share/doc/linux-doc/EDID/1920x1080.S 1366x768.S
   ```
4. Edit file `1366x768.S` with correct [values](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97023/how-to-make-edid), compile, copy to `/lib/firmware/edid`:

   - Obtain current working modeline for my laptop screen

     ```
     $ xvidtune -show
     "1366x768"     76.50   1366 1402 1450 1546    768  771  776  824 -hsync -vsync
     ```

     They are in turn: `resolution`, `clock MHz`, `hdisp`, `hsyncstart`, `hsyncend`, `htotal`, `vdisp`, `vsyncstart`, `vsyncend`, `vtotal`
   - Calculate values:

     ```
     CLOCK = 76500
     XPIX    = hdisp                               = 1366
     XBLANK  = htotal - hdisp        = 1546 - 1366 = 180
     XOFFSET = hsyncstart - hdisp    = 1402 - 1366 = 36
     XPULSE  = hsyncend - hsyncstart = 1450 - 1402 = 48

     YPIX    = vdisp = 768
     YBLANK  = vtotal - vdisp             = 824 - 768      = 56
     YOFFSET = 63 + vsyncstart - vdisp    = 63 + 771 - 768 = 66
     YPULSE  = 63 + vsyncend - vsyncstart = 63 + 776 - 771 = 68

     TIMING_NAME "Linux HDR"
     CRC 0xcd
     ```
   - Final version `1366x768.S`:

     ```
     $ cat 1366x768.S
     /* EDID */
     #define VERSION 1
     #define REVISION 3

     /* Display */
     #define CLOCK 76500 /* kHz */
     #define XPIX 1366
     #define YPIX 768
     #define XY_RATIO XY_RATIO_16_9
     #define XBLANK 180
     #define YBLANK 56
     #define XOFFSET 36
     #define XPULSE 48
     #define YOFFSET 66
     #define YPULSE 68
     #define DPI 96
     #define VFREQ 60 /* Hz */
     #define TIMING_NAME "Linux HDR"
     #define ESTABLISHED_TIMINGS_BITS 0x00 /* none */
     #define HSYNC_POL 1
     #define VSYNC_POL 1
     #define CRC 0xcd

     #include "edid.S"
     ```
   - Compile files and check if no errors using `edid-decode` (`sudo apt-get install edid-decode`):

     ```
     $ make clean && make
     rm 1920x1080.o 1366x768.o

     $ ls -1 *.bin
     1366x768.bin
     1920x1080.bin

     $ edid-decode 1366x768.bin
     Extracted contents:
     header:          00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00
     serial number:   31 d8 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 16
     version:         01 03
     basic params:    6d 23 14 78 ea
     chroma info:     5e c0 a4 59 4a 98 25 20 50 54
     established:     00 00 00
     standard:        8b c0 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
     descriptor 1:    e2 1d 56 b4 50 00 38 30 24 30 35 00 63 c8 10 00 00 1e
     descriptor 2:    00 00 00 ff 00 4c 69 6e 75 78 20 23 30 0a 20 20 20 20
     descriptor 3:    00 00 00 fd 00 3b 3d 30 32 08 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20
     descriptor 4:    00 00 00 fc 00 4c 69 6e 75 78 20 48 44 52 0a 20 20 20
     extensions:      00
     checksum:        cd

     Manufacturer: LNX Model 0 Serial Number 0
     Made week 5 of 2012
     EDID version: 1.3
     Analog display, Input voltage level: 0.7/0.7 V
     Sync: Separate Composite Serration 
     Maximum image size: 35 cm x 20 cm
     Gamma: 2.20
     DPMS levels: Standby Suspend Off
     RGB color display
     First detailed timing is preferred timing
     Established timings supported:
     Standard timings supported:
       1360x816@60Hz
     Detailed mode: Clock 76.500 MHz, 355 mm x 200 mm
                    1366 1402 1450 1546 hborder 0
                     768  771  776  824 vborder 0
                    +hsync +vsync
     Serial number: Linux #0
         Monitor ranges: 59-61HZ vertical, 48-50kHz horizontal, max dotclock 80MHz
     Monitor name: Linux HDR
        Checksum: 0xcd

     $ edid-decode 1920x1080.bin
     Extracted contents:
     header:          00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00
     serial number:   31 d8 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 16
     version:         01 03
     basic params:    6d 32 1c 78 ea
     chroma info:     5e c0 a4 59 4a 98 25 20 50 54
     established:     00 00 00
     standard:        d1 c0 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01
     descriptor 1:    02 3a 80 18 71 38 2d 40 58 2c 45 00 f4 19 11 00 00 1e
     descriptor 2:    00 00 00 ff 00 4c 69 6e 75 78 20 23 30 0a 20 20 20 20
     descriptor 3:    00 00 00 fd 00 3b 3d 42 44 0f 00 0a 20 20 20 20 20 20
     descriptor 4:    00 00 00 fc 00 4c 69 6e 75 78 20 46 48 44 0a 20 20 20
     extensions:      00
     checksum:        05

     Manufacturer: LNX Model 0 Serial Number 0
     Made week 5 of 2012
     EDID version: 1.3
     Analog display, Input voltage level: 0.7/0.7 V
     Sync: Separate Composite Serration 
     Maximum image size: 50 cm x 28 cm
     Gamma: 2.20
     DPMS levels: Standby Suspend Off
     RGB color display
     First detailed timing is preferred timing
     Established timings supported:
     Standard timings supported:
       1920x1152@60Hz
     Detailed mode: Clock 148.500 MHz, 500 mm x 281 mm
                    1920 2008 2052 2200 hborder 0
                    1080 1084 1089 1125 vborder 0
                    +hsync +vsync
     Serial number: Linux #0
         Monitor ranges: 59-61HZ vertical, 66-68kHz horizontal, max dotclock 150MHz
     Monitor name: Linux FHD
        Checksum: 0x5
     ```
   - Copy files to `/lib/firmware/edid`

     ```
     $ sudo cp *.bin /lib/firmware/edid
     ```
5. Update `initramfs`, hook script should add edid files (they are there, I've checked)

   ```
   $ sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
6. On boot, edit grub command line (pressed shift on boot to show grub menu and after press `e`) from:

   ```
   linux   /vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff
   ```

   to

   ```
   linux   /vmlinuz-3.13.0-24-generic root=/dev/mapper/mint--vg-root ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=card0-LVDS-1:/lib/firmware/edid/1366x768.bin drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=card0-HDMI-A-1:/lib/firmware/edid/1920x1080.bin
   ```

Also I've tried setting it just for one monitor. But no luck at all. I'm starting to think that it is not a problem with resolution but with plymouth image itself. When I see boot image it is not blurred, stretched or anything and Linux mint logo is sharp and clear. It's just smaller than my screen and placed in left top part of my laptop and HDMI screen.

I've found [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/572155) that is really similar to my problem. So I think I must wait for them to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

Your monitor provides information about itself using a digital standard called EDID. The kernel reads this information when detecting a display device and automatically configures its display to match as near as it can the display device's *native* resolution. LCD devices can, in truth, support only one resolution - their *native* resolution - and *emulate* all others. From [wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data):

> Extended display identification data *(EDID)* is a data structure provided by a digital display to describe its capabilities to a video source (e.g. graphics card or set-top box). It is what enables a modern personal computer to know what kinds of monitors are connected to it. EDID is defined by a standard published by the Video Electronics Standards Association (VESA). The EDID includes manufacturer name and serial number, product type, phosphor or filter type, timings supported by the display, display size, luminance data and (for digital displays only) pixel mapping data.

The problem with this is that very often the provided *EDID* is *wrong* or in some way corrupt - this is generally due to lazy or misguided manufacturers that have to program that information into the device's firmware. It may even result from a bad HDMI wire, but the chances of this are much slimmer as a digital cable is *much* more likely to simply not work at all. But there are other possibilities, if you use KMS you'll likely find this interesting:

> Today, with the advent of Kernel Mode Setting, a graphics board is either correctly working because all components follow the standards - or the computer is unusable, because the screen remains dark after booting or it displays the wrong area. Cases when this happens are:

- The graphics board does not recognize the monitor.
- The graphics board is unable to detect any EDID data.
- The graphics board incorrectly forwards EDID data to the driver.
- The monitor sends no or bogus EDID data.
- A KVM sends its own EDID data instead of querying the connected monitor.

> Adding the kernel parameter "nomodeset" helps in most cases, but causes restrictions later on.

*∆That∆* is an excerpt from [kernel.org's own HOWTO.txt](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/EDID/HOWTO.txt) for KMS EDID's. That text file is located in the [same folder](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/EDID/) as five standard resolution EDID's which you can provide the kernel at boot via a kernel parameter and initramfs in order to bypass your monitor's provided EDID.

If you are using one of the open source display drivers you are using kernel mode setting and can for instance use any of the five KMS EDID resolution bypass presets already mentioned. Alternatively you can provide your own EDID file entirely that the kernel will use instead of the information provided it by the display device.

See [this section](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_mode_setting#Forcing_modes_and_EDID) of the Arch Linux wiki for more information, but probably [this AskUbuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144088/how-to-load-edid-firmware-with-drm-kms-helper) would be better targeted toward your distribution.

If you are not using KMS and are instead using either the nvidia or AMD closed-source drivers then, as far as I'm aware, your chances of handling boot-time resolutions reliably are almost nil. It may be possible to configure these in `grub` or another boot loader *before* any initramfs image is mounted, but the likelihood that doing so will later interfere with the closed-source drivers' own resolution configuration when `X` starts is pretty high. If you are *very* lucky your motherboard manufacturer has kindly provided you a setting in UEFI firmware for configuring boot-time resolution and you can set it there before even any secondary boot-loader such as `grub` is loaded at all. I've never personally known anyone so lucky as that, though.

Comment: Interesting. I have Intel graphic at work so there should be `KMS` enabled by default. So all I need to do is enable `KMS` in `intramfs` (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_Graphics#Kernel_Mode_Setting), find correct `EDID` files for both monitors, include them to `initramfs` and add boot parameter `drm_kms_helper.edid_firmware=LVDS1:edid/for_LVDS1.bin,HDMI1:edid/for_HDMI1.bin`. Is that correct?

Comment: @piotrekkr - That should do it, yes. One interesting thing about this is that you can also set them to always be enabled - even when they're not connected - so the X display that would normally be assigned to them when they are can be set to always be enabled whether or not they're there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try it tomorrow. Two more question. Will there be any problems when I disconnect external monitor and use another monitor with different native resolution? Will it try to switch to new resolution or will it stick to old one set by boot option? In your comment you wrote that I can set them to be enabled always. What do you mean by *them*? EDID files with correct resolutions?

Comment: @piotrekkr - Yes, you can configure the display ports that the EDIDs describe to always be active. Regarding the possibility of using other monitors on the same port ... Hmm. I'm not really certain what might happen in that context. I guess the worst case is a reboot to a configuration lacking the kernel parameter would be necessary, but I've never had occasion to find out.

Comment: I've tried your solution but with no luck. Can you look at my updated question?

Comment: @piotrekkr - I think the problem is that the EDID files you supply are the same EDIDs that the monitor supplies so there shouldn't be any difference in behavior. It's not the filename that matters - it's the data within the file that matters. I've just found [this awesome answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97150/52934) about how to create a custom EDID. I can go into more detail if you like, but the same modes the monitor requested before are still being requested at boot. By the way - that's good boot-work up there. Not a lot of people understand how that kind of stuff is done.

Comment: I've created custom `EDID` files but still no luck. I'm also starting to think that it is bug in pymouth, not resolution problem. See my edit and thank you for help.